# Pagination with an array of post objects?

Tags: posts, loop, multisite, pagination, get-posts

I am curious, I have the following code:

```
    foreach ($this->networkBlogs as $siteBlog) {
        switch_to_blog($siteBlog['blog_id']);
        foreach (get_posts() as $postObject) {
            array_push($this->blogPosts, $postObject);
        }
    }
```

What this does is goes through each of the network blogs, which is fetched via: `$this->networkBlogs = wp_get_sites();`

I then switch to that blog, get all the posts and push them all into an array. The end result is an array like (using `var_dump()`):

```
array (size=15)
  0 => 
    object(WP_Post)[343]
      public 'ID' => int 59
      public 'post_author' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'post_date' => string '2015-07-02 19:50:19' (length=19)
      public 'post_date_gmt' => string '2015-07-02 19:50:19' (length=19)
      public 'post_content' => string 'Content here' (length=12)
      public 'post_title' => string 'Something Else' (length=14)
      public 'post_excerpt' => string 'Content hereContent hereContent hereContent hereContent here' (length=60)
      public 'post_status' => string 'publish' (length=7)
      public 'comment_status' => string 'open' (length=4)
      public 'ping_status' => string 'open' (length=4)
      public 'post_password' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_name' => string 'something-else' (length=14)
      public 'to_ping' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'pinged' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_modified' => string '2015-07-02 20:09:33' (length=19)
      public 'post_modified_gmt' => string '2015-07-02 20:09:33' (length=19)
      public 'post_content_filtered' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_parent' => int 0
      public 'guid' => string 'http://vagrantpresssunrise.dev/wordpress/?p=59' (length=46)
      public 'menu_order' => int 0
      public 'post_type' => string 'post' (length=4)
      public 'post_mime_type' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'comment_count' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
  1 => 
    object(WP_Post)[368]
      public 'ID' => int 57
      public 'post_author' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'post_date' => string '2015-07-02 19:50:02' (length=19)
      public 'post_date_gmt' => string '2015-07-02 19:50:02' (length=19)
      public 'post_content' => string 'Post Content' (length=12)
      public 'post_title' => string 'Another Post' (length=12)
      public 'post_excerpt' => string 'Content hereContent hereContent hereContent hereContent here' (length=60)
      public 'post_status' => string 'publish' (length=7)
      public 'comment_status' => string 'open' (length=4)
      public 'ping_status' => string 'open' (length=4)
      public 'post_password' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_name' => string 'another-post' (length=12)
      public 'to_ping' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'pinged' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_modified' => string '2015-07-02 20:05:44' (length=19)
      public 'post_modified_gmt' => string '2015-07-02 20:05:44' (length=19)
      public 'post_content_filtered' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'post_parent' => int 0
      public 'guid' => string 'http://vagrantpresssunrise.dev/wordpress/?p=57' (length=46)
      public 'menu_order' => int 0
      public 'post_type' => string 'post' (length=4)
      public 'post_mime_type' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'comment_count' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
...
```

This is easy to parse through, There are 15 post objects in here but my pagination rules set in the back end of WP state only 10 posts per page. So my question is:

**Can I convert either the function I use to get all these posts or this array of posts into something where I can use default WP Pagination methods?**